# XDocument or XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, linq-to-xml

I am now learning [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) but I've just ran into [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) and when I try to search the difference or benefits of them I can't find something useful, could you please tell me why you would use one over another ?

Comment: I'm wondering why the documentation guys in Microsoft did not put any note or remark in MSDN to clarify their differences or when to use what.

Comment: Some info on msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387021.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. And a performance question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383919/performance-xdocument-versus-xmldocument. Personally I have found it easier to work with LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 558, accepted):

If you're using .NET version 3.0 or lower, you *have* to use `XmlDocument` aka the classic DOM API. Likewise you'll find there are some other APIs which will expect this.

If you get the choice, however, I would thoroughly recommend using `XDocument` aka LINQ to XML. It's *much* simpler to create documents and process them. For example, it's the difference between:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("root");
root.SetAttribute("name", "value");
XmlElement child = doc.CreateElement("child");
child.InnerText = "text node";
root.AppendChild(child);
doc.AppendChild(root);
```

and

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("root",
                 new XAttribute("name", "value"),
                 new XElement("child", "text node")));
```

Namespaces are pretty easy to work with in LINQ to XML, unlike any other XML API I've ever seen:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://somewhere.com";
XElement element = new XElement(ns + "elementName");
// etc
```

LINQ to XML also works really well with LINQ - its construction model allows you to build elements with sequences of sub-elements really easily:

```
// Customers is a List<Customer>
XElement customersElement = new XElement("customers",
    customers.Select(c => new XElement("customer",
        new XAttribute("name", c.Name),
        new XAttribute("lastSeen", c.LastOrder)
        new XElement("address",
            new XAttribute("town", c.Town),
            new XAttribute("firstline", c.Address1),
            // etc
    ));
```

It's all a lot more declarative, which fits in with the general LINQ style.

Now as Brannon mentioned, these are in-memory APIs rather than streaming ones (although `XStreamingElement` supports lazy output). `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter` are the normal ways of streaming XML in .NET, but you can mix all the APIs to some extent. For example, you can stream a large document but use LINQ to XML by positioning an `XmlReader` at the start of an element, reading an `XElement` from it and processing it, then moving on to the next element etc. There are various blog posts about this technique, [here's one I found with a quick search](http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/09/02/streaming-into-linq-to-xml-using-c-custom-iterators-and-xmlreader/).

Comment: Could you tell me why they are different ? I mean yeah XDocument looks pretty neat but as for DOM level difference, aren't they both xml, is there any scheme that shows both Microsoft X-DOM and W3C Compliant DOM ? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "scheme" and what do you mean by "shows"? Yes, they both deal with standard XML, but LINQ to XML is just a nicer API for most things. A lot of the technology *behind* LINQ to XML simply wasn't available before .NET 3.5.

Comment: I mean whether their document object models are different ?

Comment: Well they're both APIs for XML itself, so in that sense they're not different, no. I suspect both have some limitations (and there's a LINQ to XML one which I know about but can't remember off the top of my head) but in most cases you can just treat them as being the same model with slightly different representations.

Comment: @JonSkeet in your last example with the customer list. How would one proceed if foreach customer in the list I want to create a pair of XElement, like so : `<customers><id>1</id><name>Bob</name><id>2</id><name>Frank</name></customers>`. I've tried in the select to create more than one element separating with a comma like so : `.Select(c => new XElement("id", c.id), new XElement("name", c.name));` But apparently thats not the syntax

Comment: @WizLiz: I suggest you ask a new question rather than us trying to deal with it in comments.

Comment: At first I thought this would fit this answer, then I decided to ask a new one which has been done and answered. Thanks :)

Comment: This is ancient, but the "much simpler to create documents" (using XDocument) is pretty thin.  It is trivial to add your own XmlDocument/XmlElement extension methods to get the Linq-esq functional chaining.  For ex:
`public static XmlElement AppendElement(this XmlElement parent,
            string prefix, string name, string ns)
        {
            var child = parent.OwnerDocument.CreateElement(prefix, name, ns);
            parent.AppendChild(child);
            return child;
        }`

Comment: @SensorSmith: That doesn't cover all the other bonuses though, like automatic flattening of sequences, handling of DateTime etc. You could add extensions methods for all that too, but why reinvent LINQ to XML when you can just use it instead?

Comment: Is there any way to use `XPath` notations in conjunction with the`XLinQ`, in my query, if the same deals with `xmlns:*`?

Comment: @Cylian: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. I suggest you ask with much more details in a new post.

Answer (score 67):

I am surprised none of the answers so far mentions the fact that **`XmlDocument` provides no line information**, while **`XDocument` does** (through the [`IXmlLineInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.ixmllineinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface).

This can be a critical feature in some cases (for example if you want to report errors in an XML, or keep track of where elements are defined in general) and you better be aware of this before you happily start to implement using `XmlDocument`, to later discover you have to change it all.

Comment: And I am surprised nobody noticed that your statement is inversely true. XmlDocument DOES provide the line information while XDocument doesn't.

Comment: @VVS: you got me worried for a moment that I had made a terrible typo, but after double checking, I confirm that `XDocument` does provide line information. See [XDocument.Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538371%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with `LoadOptions.SetLineInfo` as a second argument. If you know a way to get line information with `XmlDocument` I am curious; back when I wrote this answer I couldn't find any. This other answer seems to confirm: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33622102/253883

Comment: "and you better be aware of this before you happily start to implement using XmlDocument, to later discover you have to change it all."

Guess what I just did :)

Answer (score 45):

`XmlDocument` is great for developers who are familiar with the XML DOM object model.  It's been around for a while, and more or less corresponds to a W3C standard.  It supports manual navigation as well as `XPath` node selection.

`XDocument` powers the LINQ to XML feature in .NET 3.5.  It makes heavy use of `IEnumerable<>` and can be easier to work with in straight C#.

Both document models require you to load the entire document into memory (unlike `XmlReader` for example).

Comment: I think you meant "and can be easier to work with in straight VB.net".  Because VB supports direct creation of elements where C# still requires code.

Answer (score 31):

As mentioned elsewhere, undoubtedly, Linq to Xml makes creation and alteration of xml documents a breeze in comparison to `XmlDocument`, and the `XNamespace ns + "elementName"` syntax makes for pleasurable reading when dealing with namespaces.

One thing worth mentioning for `xsl` and `xpath` die hards to note is that it IS possible to still execute arbitrary `xpath 1.0` expressions on Linq 2 Xml `XNodes` by including:

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
```

and then we can navigate and project data using `xpath` via these extension methods:

- [XPathSelectElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351355(v=vs.110).aspx) - Single Element
- [XPathSelectElements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176(v=vs.110).aspx) - Node Set
- [XPathEvaluate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341675(v=vs.110).aspx) - Scalars and others

For instance, given the Xml document:

```
<xml>
    <foo>
        <baz id="1">10</baz>
        <bar id="2" special="1">baa baa</bar>
        <baz id="3">20</baz>
        <bar id="4" />
        <bar id="5" />
    </foo>
    <foo id="123">Text 1<moo />Text 2
    </foo>
</xml>
```

We can evaluate:

```
var node = xele.XPathSelectElement("/xml/foo[@id='123']");
var nodes = xele.XPathSelectElements(
"//moo/ancestor::xml/descendant::baz[@id='1']/following-sibling::bar[not(@special='1')]");
var sum = xele.XPathEvaluate("sum(//foo[not(moo)]/baz)");
```

Answer (score 28):

`XDocument` is from the LINQ to XML API, and `XmlDocument` is the standard DOM-style API for XML. If you know DOM well, and don't want to learn LINQ to XML, go with `XmlDocument`. If you're new to both, check out [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387021.aspx) that compares the two, and pick which one you like the looks of better.

I've just started using LINQ to XML, and I love the way you create an XML document using functional construction. It's really nice. DOM is clunky in comparison.

Answer (score 14):

Also, note that `XDocument` is supported in Xbox 360 and Windows Phone OS 7.0. 
If you target them, develop for `XDocument` or migrate from `XmlDocument`.

Answer (score -10):

I believe that `XDocument` makes a lot more object creation calls.  I suspect that for when you're handling a lot of XML documents, `XMLDocument` will be faster.

One place this happens is in managing scan data.  Many scan tools output their data in XML (for obvious reasons).  If you have to process a lot of these scan files, I think you'll have better performance with `XMLDocument`.

Comment: I think you should back your comment up with figures next time, as I believe you may be wrong. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codejunkie/archive/2008/10/08/xmldocument-vs-xelement-performance.aspx