# Performance: XDocument versus XmlDocument

Tags: .net, xml, performance, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

I have read a comparison between the two [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542073/xdocument-or-xmldocument). This is primarily a question of performance, relating to both memory and speed.

I've got several XML documents that are upwards of 100 - 300 K in size. I've noticed that there is some lag when loading this information into an `XDocument` rather than an `XmlDocument` object.

- Is there a serious performance difference between these two objects?
- Do they access the content of the XML differently?
- When working with a string of XML, which is preferred, or is there a difference?

The end use of these object is to run queries (`XPath` or LINQ, depending) on the object in question.

Answer (score 21):

XmlDocument is a purely managed implemenation of the Document Object Model.  There is no interop with any COM components, such as the MSXML library.  Any claim otherwise is completely bogus.  The entire XLinq set of APIs came about as a friendlier way to interact with XML with introduction of LINQ in the .NET Framework.

If you're trying to maximize performance and are comfortable using XPath, try using the XmlDocument and using [compiled XPath expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/093b7219.aspx).

Comment: And LINQ doesn't magically improve performance. Nor is that the goal of LINQ - the goal is to increase programmer productivity, which it may if you already know LINQ and you don't know the "old" XML APIs the framework offers.

Answer (score 8):

`XmlReader` is the lowest API in .NET which all other XML APIs in .NET use under the scenes. Naturally that means it's the hardest to deal with, as well as fastest. It's a streaming API, so it is best fit for memory as well.

Between `XmlDocument` and `XDocument` aka Linq to XML, here are some raw numbers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/codejunkie/xmldocument-vs-xelement-performance

which finds `XDocument` class being faster/more efficient. Programmer productivity/efficiency shouldn't be ignored as well. Personally I find it easier to work with `XDocument`.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else is still looking for the answer...
I have managed to do some benchmarking by myself. It seems that the XDocument exceeds the XmlDocument quite substantially. Of course, you could be tempted to involve the XmlReader in this, but this is a topic for another time.

Here's my tiny benchmark result: https://github.com/zulimazuli/dotnetXmlBenchmarks