# How to update an XML file in C#

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I am having an XML file. I would like to create a new node and append it at the end of the XML file and save it back to memory.

```
<IntCal>
  <User>
    <Date>12/09/2012</Date>
    <Client>abcd</Client>
    <Jewellery>Others</Jewellery>
    <ROI>7.5</ROI>
    <Description>Some Description</Description>
  </User>
<IntCal>
```

I would like to create a new `<User>` element. Any idea how to do it.

```
 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmlDoc.Load(xmlFile);
XmlNode root_node;

//XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/IntCal/User");

XmlDocument new_node = new XmlDocument();
root_node = xmlDoc.CreateElement("IntCal");
xmlDoc.AppendChild(root_node);
```

Thanks

Comment: Little bit offtopic ... but solutions with LINQ to XML are usually much easier

Answer (score 3):

Reference:  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw1ys7w6(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw1ys7w6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
    XmlElement elem = xmlDoc.CreateElement("User");
    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(elem);
```

If you want to go the LINQ route, you could do:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
xDoc.Element("IntCal")
    .Add(new XElement("User"));
```

Personally, I'd opt for the XDocument and use LINQ but either way works.
Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx

Answer (score 2):

*XmlDocument* is an old school, why don't you use *XDocument*, simple and easy:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
xDoc.Root.Add(new XElement("User", 
                  new XElement("Client", "John"), 
                  new XElement("Jewellery", "Others")));
xDoc.Save(xmlFile);
```

References:

1. [XDocument or XmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542073/xdocument-or-xmldocument)
2. [Performance: XDocument versus XmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383919/xdocument-versus-xmldocument)