# what is the difference between xml document and xml

Tags: c#, xml

We know xml is used for storing data,which can be ported across platforms(underlying principle of webservice). But i am confused with the term xmldocument. What is actually xml document? does that the alternate name of XMl??

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542073/xdocument-or-xmldocument

Comment: Are you talking about the class XmlDocument, or more terminology?

Comment: I dont want the difference between Xdocument and xml documnet, i want what is the terminology xmldocument,does that the one xml?

Comment: @Henric, what is the difference between english and a book?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @nfechner, how on earth is "What have you tried?" relevent to this question?

Comment: so you mean what ever contents in the xml like elements including root node and other datas if i want use i need to instantiate xmldocument class. So purely a programatic representation of xml rite?

Comment: @KirkWoll Maybe the link to "How to Ask" would have been enough. I usually add both links to questions like this, as I think the poster will benefit from reading both. And it's a lot nicer than saying JFGI.

Comment: @Henric, yes, XML is a language, `XmlDocument` is a C# class used to read/write XML files/documents.

Comment: @Kirk Woll thanks ,thats the one, i really confused to see that word in lot of places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question.
XMLDocument represents an XML document, it's simple :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.80).aspx

XML is a markup language and XMLDocument is a class to read an XML file.