# Neatest way to extract 'text' value from an XmlNode?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

Given the code:

```
  var doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.LoadXml(@"<a>
                    <b>test
                        <c>test2</c>
                    </b>
                </a>");
  var node = doc.SelectNodes("/a/b")[0];
```

I want to then extract the 'text' value of `node b` - in this case "test", without retrieving all text elements from all child nodes (as .`innerText` does)

I find myself resorting to this code

```
 var elementText = node.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>().First(a => a.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text).Value;
```

As unfortunately `node.Value` does something else in this case

is there a neater/inbuilt way without resorting to linq casting? that doesnt involve me doing something like;

```
foreach (var childNode in node.ChildNodes)
   if (childNode.NodeType==XmlNodeType.Text)
    ...
```

Comment: first idea, abandon `XmlDocument` and use `XDocument`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx

Comment: If you are stuck on .net 2.0 or prior, say so in the question.

Comment: @Jodrell, nope Im not, thanks for the `XDocument` suggestion, im looking at it now.

Comment: Id say you should use XPath if you want the neatest way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer `XDocument` to `XmlDocument`, I think it's easier to work with. You can easily get a value using the `Element` method to find the "b" element, and then using the `Value` property.

```
using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using(var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(@"<a>
                                 <b>test
                                     <c>test2</c>
                                 </b>
                             </a>");
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
        Console.WriteLine(doc.Element("a").Element("b").FirstNode.ToString());
    }
}
```

EDIT: As noted in comments, that would get the incorrect value. I've updated it correctly.

Comment: agreed, on .Net 3.5 up there is no reason to use `XmlDocument`.

Comment: There's nothing _wrong_ with it, I think it's just preferred. Here's a good SO link describing the differences between XDocument and XmlDocument: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542073/xdocument-or-xmldocument

Comment: It does not get "test", it get "test\ntest2"

Answer (score 0):

You want to use node.InnerText instead of Value. So you would have this:

```
 foreach(XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
 {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        s = child.InnerText;
    }
    else
    {
        s = s.Replace(child.InnerText, "");
    }
 }

   s.Trim();
```

Comment: no dude, thats going to concat all child text elements aswell, so i would get `testtest2`. I've clarified my question.

Answer (score 0):

In LINQ2XML you can do this

```
foreach(XNode elm in doc.Descendants("b").OfType<XText>())
{
//elm has the text
}
```