# how to change xml string value on fly

Tags: c#, xml, string

I have an xml response string and I want to change a value inside and log it.

```
<xml>
<ns2:abcd>
<password>sample</password>
</ns2:abcd>
```

I want to change the password value into encrypted version.

I am have tried using `XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode` but was thinking is there any better way than this?

Comment: start here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx, probably with `XElement.Parse`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Btw you need `ns2` namespace to be declared, otherwise your xml will not be valid. After adding namespace definition, you can parse and modify your xml with Linq to Xml:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var passwordElement = xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//password");
passwordElement.Value = Encrypt((string)passwordElement);
xdoc.Save(path_to_xml);
```

Comment: Is `SelectSingleNode` a member of `XDocument`?

Comment: @Jodrell you should add `using System.Xml.XPath;` for `XPathSelectElement` extension

Comment: You are correct and I learned something. I've never had cause to prefer XPath to Linq.

Answer (score 1):

No - there is no better way than using proper XML classes.

XmlDocument or XDocument would be perfectly fine for this task. If you XML is very large you may want to look into streaming with XmlReader (unlikely necessary in your case).

Comment: Prefer `XDocument` to `XmlDocument` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542073/xdocument-or-xmldocument

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider looking into xsd.exe. With xsd.exe, you can deserialize your xml into a type-safe object model. From there, it's easy to manipulate the data.