# How to change value in xml string?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following method

```
string UpdateXmlString(string xmlString) {...}
```

I would like to find all tags which name contain `password` and delete a value;

Before:

```
<job xmlns:i=\"...\" xmlns=\"...">
<password>asdfasdf</password>
<adminPassword>asd</adminPassword>
...</job>
```

Expected result:

```
<job xmlns:i=\"..." xmlns=\"...">
<password></password>
<adminPassword></adminPassword>
...</job>
```

How to implement this method?

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Why are you working in terms of *strings* when the .NET Framework has an entire *namespace* dedicated to XML tooling that understands XML *natively*?

Comment: And, also, why are you trying to implement a method that suggests it makes changes when it's returning `void` and .NET strings are immutable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change xml string value on fly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485437/how-to-change-xml-string-value-on-fly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply be using XmlDocument or XDocument to parse this. I wouldn't manipulate XML strings manually.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace XDocumentTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><rootElement>";
                xml += "<user id=\"1\"><password>temp</password></user>";
                xml += "<user id=\"2\"><adminPassword>foobar</adminPassword></user>";
                xml += "<user id=\"3\"><somePassWORDelement>foobarXYZ</somePassWORDelement></user>";
                xml += "</rootElement>";
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
                foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants().Where(
                    e => e.Name.ToString().ToLower().Contains("password")))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(element);
                    // Delete your value here. Either changing the text node
                    // or by removing the password node. E.g.

                    element.Value = string.Empty;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

            while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `Descendants` find tag with name `adminPassword`?

Comment: Sure. Just change the tag name in the code above from password to adminPassword.

Comment: No, as I said in my question I would like to find all tags with `password` in name( I mean `name.Contains("password")`)

Comment: You could have been clearer on that point. Might be worth updating your question to state that the element name should CONTAIN password rather "with password in name". That seems to suggest that you want elements named password. I'll update my answer in a moment to reflect this new requirement.

Comment: Okay, I've updated the example accordingly to look for any instance of password, case-insensitive, in a full console app example.

Comment: foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants().Where(
                    e => e.Name.ToString().ToLower().Contains("password")))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(element);
                    // Delete your value here. Either changing the text node
                    // or by removing the password node. E.g.

                    element.Value = string.Empty;
                }

Helped me to change values in an XML string I had.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use XPathNavigator.

In MSDN are some examples that will help you:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx28tfx1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(path); 

var element = doc.Descendants("YOUR_Descendants")
                    .Where(arg => arg.Attribute("ExampleID").Value == "3" )// 
                    .Single();

element.Element("UpdateElements")
    .Element("UpdateElements_fc").Value = "222";// update
                doc.Save(path); //save
```