# Replace one Xml tag value with another tag value in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml-parsing

I have been trying to do this in C# to write a class for xml files in my folder to replace NULL value for MyXmlElement12 with Value from MyXmlElement as below +datetimestamp:

```
<MyXmlType>
   <MyXmlElement>Value</MyXmlElement>
  <MyXmlElement12></MyXmlElement12>
</MyXmlType>
```

Could someone please help? I have been able to get the value from first element and add a time stamp as below. But how do I update the second xml tag with this value `replacestring` I have below?

```
 public Form1()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("C:\\Users\\1\\1.xml");

    XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//MyXmlElement");

    string text = node.InnerText;
    string t = text + DateTime.Now.ToString();
    replacestring= t.Replace("/", "");
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Path);
doc.Element("MyXmlType")
   .Element("MyXmlElement12")
   .Value += DateTime.Now.ToString();
doc.Save(Path);
```

Comment: I am using XMLdocument above, is this same as Xdocument? Is there a way it can be done using XMLdocument?

Comment: XmlDocument is different than XDocument. XDocument allows you to use LINQ. I haven't personally used XmlDocument but you can see the difference here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542073/xdocument-or-xmldocument

Comment: I got it working Thanks a lot. How can I loop through each xml file in a folder for this I am doing right now                       XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\1.xml");

Comment: Use List<string> MyFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Dir", "*.xml").ToList(); and iterate through the list.