# "Expression must evaluate to a node-set."

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have a problem

My XML File is here:

```
<altinkaynak>

   <DOVIZ>
     <ADI>Tarih</ADI>
     <ALIS>24.07.2013 18:59:45</ALIS>
     <SATIS/>
   </DOVIZ>
   <DOVIZ>
      <ADI>USD</ADI>
      <ALIS>1.9120</ALIS>
      <SATIS>1.9220</SATIS>
   </DOVIZ>
   <DOVIZ>
      <ADI>EUR</ADI>
      <ALIS>2.5280</ALIS>
      <SATIS>2.5430</SATIS>
   </DOVIZ> 
</altinkaynak>
```

How am I parse this XML file

I coded that way but I got a parse error message;

```
if (tip == DövizKuruTipi2.Alış)
Line 44: return Decimal.Parse(doc.SelectNodes("//ALTINKAYNAK/DOVIZ/ADI=" + dovizKuru2 + "/ALIS")[0].InnerText.Replace('.', ','));
```

> Expression must evaluate to a node-set

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Reason for the Error**

As per the error message, `.SelectNodes()` requires that the `xpath` string parameter evaluates to a node set, e.g. this xpath will return an `XmlNodeList` containing 3 nodes:

```
var nodeSet = document.SelectNodes("/altinkaynak/DOVIZ");
```

Supplying an `xpath` which returns a single node is also acceptable - the returned `XmlNodeList` will just have a single node:

```
var nodeSet = document.SelectNodes("(/altinkaynak/DOVIZ)[1]");
```

However, it is not possible to return non-node values, such as scalar expressions:

```
var nodeSet = document.SelectNodes("count(/altinkaynak/DOVIZ)");
```

> Error: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.

Instead for `XmlDocument`, you would need to create a navigator, compile an expression, and evaluate it:

```
 var navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
 var expr = navigator.Compile("count(/altinkaynak/DOVIZ)");
 var count = navigator.Evaluate(expr); // 3 (nodes)
```

If you switch your Xml parsing stack from using `XmlDocument` to a `Linq to Xml` `XDocument` there is a [much more concise way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27583026/314291) to evaluate scalar expressions:

```
var count = xele.XPathEvaluate("count(/altinkaynak/DOVIZ)");
```

**Badly formed Xpath**

This same error (`Expression must evaluate to a node-set`) is also frequently returned for `xpath`s which are invalid altogether

```
 var nodeSet = document.SelectNodes("{Insert some really badly formed xpath here!}");
```

> Error: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.

**OP's Question**

You have an error in your Xpath. What you probably want is this:

```
doc.SelectNodes("//ALTINKAYNAK/DOVIZ[ADI='" + dovizKuru2 + "']/ALIS") // ...
```

which will return the `ALIS` child of the `DOVIZ` element which has an `ADI` child with a value of `dovizKuru2` (which is presumably a variable for currency such as `USD`)

Comment: Actually `Some/Really=badly[@formed='xpath']` is syntactically valid and returns a boolean. If you replace it by `A/B = C[@X=3]` you can see that it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error because my Xpath expression was invalid. I was using `==` for equality instead of a single `=`. My expression was `[SomeNode == 'SomeValue']` but should have been `[SomeNode = 'SomeValue']`.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this because I had `//` at the end of my Xpath by accident.

**Incorrect**

`table.SelectNodes(".//tr[1]//td[1]//");`

**Correct**

`table.SelectNodes(".//tr[1]//td[1]");`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had commented a node1 tag in one of my config xml for debugging. So it was throwing this error.

I just removed the unwanted node tag. It worked.