# Get node property of XmlDocument in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm using this xml structure:

```
<park>
  <car title="Ferrari" available="true">
    <url>http://www.ferrari.com/</url>
  </rss>
</park>
```

And this is my code in C#:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("Settings.xml");
            XmlNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes("/park/car");

            foreach (XmlNode item in list)
            {
                   string x = item["@title"].InnerText;
            }
```

I just want to get "title" property but i can't get it working. I'm using "@" but without success.

Comment: there's an error in your xml - `car` isn't closed and `/rss` does not have a starting element. Is that the error you are seeing?

Comment: This is outside the scope of your question, but have a look at `XDocument` instead of `XmlDocument`. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542073/xdocument-or-xmldocument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
string x = item.Attributes["title"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) for parsing xml:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("Settings.xml");
var titles = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//park/car")
                 .Select(c => (string)c.Attribute("title"));
```

Or without XPath:

```
var titles = xdoc.Descendants("park")
                 .Elements("car")
                 .Select(c => (string)c.Attribute("title"));
```