# XmlDocument combining nodes into the same line

Tags: c#, xml

I have an application that edits an XML file.

The problem is, that after I save my file, some nodes get combined onto one line.

**Example:**
I want to edit child-node B

```
<root>
    <A>
      <B>
        <C>somedata</C>
        ...
      </B>
    </A>
</root>
```

After edit I get:

```
<root>
    <A>
     <B><C>EditedData</C></B>
    </A>
</root>
```

My code Is

```
public static bool WriteNodeInnerText(List<string> NodesHirarchi, string InnerText, string PathToXml)
{
    if (NodesHirarchi.Count == 0) return false;

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(PathToXml);

    doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;

    XmlNode xmlNode;
    StringBuilder nodesPath = new StringBuilder();
    NodesHirarchi.ForEach(x => nodesPath.Append(string.Format("//{0}", x)));
    try
    {
        xmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(nodesPath.ToString());
    }
    catch (System.Xml.XPath.XPathException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Data);
        return false;
    }

    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        Indent = true,
        IndentChars = "  ",
        NewLineChars = "\r\n",
        NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace,
    };

    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(PathToXml,settings))
    {
        xmlNode.InnerText = InnerText;
        doc.Save(writer);
    }
    return true;
}
```

please Help me solve it + any comment about the code will be appreciated

Comment: Why root and A don't have angular brackets in your example?

Comment: @king.code to not over load with  unuseful text

Comment: Side note: you are trying to preserver whitespaces and automatically add more with indentation... I think you need to pick one.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yeah you probably right . I'll remove the "doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;"

Comment: @LordTitiKaka actually this is not a valid XML. XML tags are closed with "/" not with "\". I'd include a valid XML.

Comment: what do you need the xml writer for?  what's wrong with `XmlDocument.Save(string)`?

Comment: My comment about `PreserveWhitespace` seem to be wrong as `Indent=true` seem to force formatting... Are you sure it is the only place you save XML? (Consider creating standalone sample for the post that just uses `LoadXml` with constant string...)

Comment: @SamIam I saw it here in other related question, If you would be kind to provide me some logic or advantage I have no problem changing it

Comment: start by favouring `XDocument` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx over `XmlDocument`.

Comment: @Jodrell I'll check it out

Comment: its a "no-brainer" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542073/xdocument-or-xmldocument