# what does the error "System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' does not contain a def" mean?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to write a code to convert a xml file into a datatable.
I'm getting this below error

System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' does not contain a definition for 'DocumentNode' and no extension method 'DocumentNode' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What am I missing?

Below is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.XPath;

using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {



            var xdoc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(filename);
            System.Xml.XmlElement xelRoot = xdoc.DocumentElement;
            System.Xml.XmlNodeList xList = xelRoot.SelectNodes("/rulebase/security/rules/entry");

            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            string[] ColumnArray = new string[25];
            string[] RowArray = new string[25];


            foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode pNode in xList)
            {



                if (pNode.ChildNodes.Count = 0)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    string val1 = "";
                    string nodeVal = "";

                    string nodeName = pNode.name;
                    foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode childNode in pNode.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        val1 = val1 + childNode.value + ", ";
                    }
                    val1 = val1 + " ,";
                    nodeVal = val1.substring(0, val1.length - 3);

                    ColumnArray[x] = nodeName;
                    RowArray[y] = nodeVal;
                    x++;
                    y++;

                }
            }

            System.Data.DataTable table1 = new System.Data.DataTable("entry");

            foreach (string s in ColumnArray)
            {
                table1.Columns.Add(s);
            }

            System.Data.DataRow row;
            row = table1.LoadDataRow(RowArray, true);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You are mixing the X* and Xml* families of classes. That won't work. .NET has (at least) 2 distinct APIs for dealing with Xml, pick one. My choice would be the Linq based one.

Answer (score 0):

(Initially I didn't understand the comment under the question, so here some details)

The older [System.Xml.XmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) has `DocumentElement` (this is being used in the code ... I don't know where the DocumentNode mentioned in the question comes from).

[System.Xml.Linq.XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx)

- is the newer LINQ to XML class
- which does not have `DocumentElement`.
- e.g. use `xdoc.Root.Name` to get the name of the root element

For more info [XMlDocument vs XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1542101)