# Getting a whole XML node with its markups in a string

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Given the following XML example

```
<aaa>
    <bbb id="1">
        <ccc att="123"/>
        <ccc att="456"/>
        <ccc att="789"/>
    </bbb>
    <bbb id="2">
        <ccc att="321"/>
        <ccc att="654"/>
        <ccc att="987"/>
    </bbb>
</aaa>
```

as an XmlDocument object called `xDoc1`, I managed to remove the first `bbb` node thanks to its ID and an XPath instruction, leaving the second `bbb` node alone in the `aaa` one.

But now I want to get this removed node and its markups in a single string, as the `InnerText` value of this node is equal to

```
<ccc att="123"/><ccc att="456"/><ccc att="789"/>
```

but I want my string to be equal to

```
<bbb id='1'><ccc att="123"/><ccc att="456"/><ccc att="789"/></bbb>
```

How can I do so ? Using XmlDocument is mandatory.

I tried to use the `ParentNode` method, but then it includes the other `bbb` node.

My C# code for the moment :

```
xDoc1 = new XmlDocument();
xDoc1.Load("file.xml"); // Containing the given example above.

XmlNodeList nodes = xDoc1.SelectSingleNodes("//bbb[@id='1']");

foreach (XmlNode n in nodes)
{
    XmlNode parent = n.ParentNode;
    parent.RemoveChild(n);
}

// At this point, xDoc1 does not contain the first bbb node (id='1') anymore.
```

Comment: Please treat XML as code, also indenting it by four spaces. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use OuterXml property of XmlNode

```
xDoc1 = new XmlDocument();
xDoc1.Load("file.xml"); // Containing the given example above.

XmlNodeList nodes = xDoc1.SelectSingleNodes("//bbb[@id='1']");

foreach (XmlNode n in nodes)
{
    XmlNode parent = n.ParentNode;
    parent.RemoveChild(n);
    Console.WriteLine(n.OuterXml);
}
```

Comment: This works ! I'm mad at me for asking help when a single property can do the job... Thank you very much ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would firstly suggest not using `XmlDocument`. It's old tech and [has been superseded by `XDocument`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542073/xdocument-or-xmldocument), which gives you Linq2Xml and lots of explicit casting goodness when dealing with attributes etc.

Using the `XDocument` approach with Linq instead of XPath, it's quite a lot easier to work this problem:

```
var doc=XDocument.Load("file.xml");
var elToRemove = doc.Root.Elements("bbb").Single(el => (int)el.Attribute("id") == 1);
elToRemove.Remove();

Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString()); //no <bbb id="1">
Console.WriteLine(elToRemove.ToString()); //the full outer text of the removed <bbb>
```

Comment: OP also wants three child nodes "<ccc>" in removed element...probably you should update your answer to include that too

Comment: @Viru I don't understand what you are asking me to include. The descendants of the removed element remain unchanged (i.e. they are removed when the <bbb> tag is removed by virtue of being children).

Comment: Problem is that XmlDocument is used everywhere else in the project, and I must keep using it. I'm sorry I didn't specify it, editing my question. Thank you for your answer though.