# how to search the data from XML file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

am developing a search  application in **ASP.NET**. I am storing the data in an **XML** **file**.when i search for data in textbox and click submit button it should search complete XML file and retrieve the data.
this is the sample xml data...

```
<college>
    <students>
        <student>
            <name>harish</name>
            <id>002</id>
        </student>
        <student>
            <name>vamshi</name>
            <id>003</id>
        </student>
    </students>
</college>
```

now when i search in this form "**details of vamshi**" in textbox it should display the vamshi details.how can i do this..

Comment: Try using classic DOM object XmlDocument with xpath or XDocument from .net 4.0.
As per msdn it is a new version of XmlDocument and bit faster than old one.
Also Xdocument is much simpler to use. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542073/xdocument-or-xmldocument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve what you are looking for, first of all, you need to parse the xml files into C# objects. By doing that, you load xml file into memory.

Then using the built in C# xml parser function to trace the xml node by your given piece of information, in your case is "Name" attribute of student object.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\Path\To\Xml\File.xml");
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Student/Name/");
// node.Value contains "test@ABC.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom text searching process to search the xml as if it were a text file. But, I wouldn't recommend this.

The best solution in my opinion is to dump the xml file into a class `college` in your program.

To accomplish this:

1. Setup the `college` class and the `student` class to match the xml file. E.g. college should have a `List<student>` and student should have an `id` and a `name`. Probably both strings since you have leading zeros.
2. [Download and add this XML helper class to your project](http://www.mediafire.com/download/bck3gc5i83ibe2p/XMLHelper.cs).
3. dump your college xml into the class you created:

   ```
   College c = new College();        
   c = XmlHelper.FromXmlFile<College>(@"/path/to/XML/File");
   ```
4. Your College class is now populated with the data from the xml, and you can perform the search operations you desire.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote something up that might help you and it is written in C#:

```
        public string GetConnectionString(string nodeName, string xmlFile)
        {
            XmlDocument xmLDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmLDocument.Load(xmlFile);
            XmlElement root = xmLDocument.DocumentElement;
            foreach (XmlNode childNode in root.ChildNodes) 
            {
                return RecurseNodeTree(childNode, nodeName);
            }
            return null;
        }

        private string RecurseNodeTree(XmlNode xmlNode, string nodeName) 
        {
            if (xmlNode.Name == nodeName) 
            {
                return xmlNode.InnerText;
            }

            if (xmlNode.HasChildNodes) 
            {
                foreach (XmlNode childNode in xmlNode.ChildNodes) 
                {
                    if (xmlNode.NextSibling != null)
                    {
                        return RecurseNodeTree(xmlNode.NextSibling, nodeName);
                    }

                    return RecurseNodeTree(childNode, nodeName);
                }
            }

            if (xmlNode.NextSibling != null)
            {
                return RecurseNodeTree(xmlNode.NextSibling, nodeName);
            }

            return null;
        }
```

This should solve your problem or anyone else's for that matter.