# Xml file not available to all event methods using XDocument.Load in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath

I wanted to load an `XML` and have it available to all events.
In the application below, the `Button1` and `Button3` events use the loaded `XML`, whereas `Button2` won't and I had to load it within the event.
I am assuming that every time I load the file it is taking up more resources, which I am trying to avoid.
My questions are:
 - Do I have to find a different way to populate the `Datagridview` ?
 - Do I need to somehow unload the `XML` file if I need to load it somewhere else to save system resources.

I am new to programming and self taught so apologize in advance if terminology is not correct.

It is an application in a Windows form with:

- Button1 generating a listBox in ListBox1;
- Button2 populating dataGridView1 with 2 columns;
- Button3 populating comboBox1 list

**XML is as Follows:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Config>  
  <Categories>
    <Category Name="OneChar">
      <Entry>
        <Name>a</Name>
        <id>1</id>
      </Entry>
      <Entry>
        <Name>b</Name>
        <id>2</id>
      </Entry>
      <Entry>
        <Name>c</Name>
        <id>3</id>
      </Entry>
    </Category>
    <Category Name="TwoChar">
      <Entry>
        <Name>aa</Name>
        <id>11</id>
      </Entry>
      <Entry>
        <Name>bb</Name>
        <id>22</id>
      </Entry>
      <Entry>
        <Name>cc</Name>
        <id>33</id>
      </Entry>      
    </Category>   
  </Categories>
  <Schemes>
  </Schemes>
</Config>
```

**Code as Follows:**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace List_box_multiple_query
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("Config\\TestFile.xml");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            var result = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("/Config/Categories/Category [@Name='TwoChar']/Entry/Name");
            foreach (string entry in result)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(entry);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            dataGridView1.Refresh();

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("Config\\testfile.xml");
            XmlNodeList nodeList;
            XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
            nodeList = root.SelectNodes("/Config/Categories/Category[@Name='OneChar']/Entry");

            foreach (XmlNode entry in nodeList)
            {               
                int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = entry["Name"].InnerText.ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = entry["id"].InnerText.ToString();                
            }

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var result = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("/Config/Categories/Category [@Name='TwoChar']/Entry/Name");

            foreach (string entry in result)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(entry);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to be consistently using [XDocument or XmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1542101/6298965).

You can define a

```
 private Lazy<XmlDocument> docLazy = 
         new Lazy<XmlDocument>(() =>
             { 
                 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                 doc.Load("Config\\TestFile.xml");
                 return doc;
             }
         );
```

and then use it in all the handlers

```
  var doc = docLazy.Value;
```

In this way it will be loaded from file only for the first call and then cached in memory.

My previous answer was similar but for XDocument.

**reply to comments**

> Is there an easy way to select nodes in an XML and use their
>   contents...?

Yes, for example

```
var test_nodeList  = xdoc.Descendants("Category")
    .Where(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals("OneChar"))
       .Descendants("Entry");
```

instead of

```
nodeList = root.SelectNodes("/Config/Categories/Category[@Name='OneChar']/Entry");
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I have tried the fix, but the problem is the following line fails  --   XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;   -- which is the same problem as when I don't load the file within the Button click event. The intellisense message indicates " 'XDocument' does not contain a definition for 'DocumentElement' and no extension method ..."

Comment: Fixed. But doc is like xdoc: you can still do doc = xdocLazy.Value;

Comment: Apologies but I did not note your first comment about choosing XMLDocument vs XDocument. Indeed I have found the "DocumentElement" definition does not work with XDocument whereas "XPathSelectElements" does not work with XMLDocument. I quite like navigating XML with Xpath so I think XDocument it is.  The code above works but as you have mentioned, uses a mixture of XDocument and XMLDocument. Is there an easy way to select nodes in an XML and use their contents to populate a Datagrid ?

Comment: @BigVil updated my answer to reply to your last comment: pls consider accepting it, thanks :-)

Comment: Appreciate the help. As an aside, there may be a closing parentheses missing from initial definition and may be worth editing in case anyone uses this case as a reference. Big Vil

Comment: I have accepted the answer however my current foreach loop doesn't work after the statement provided. How do I cycle through the var test_nodelist  to extract "name" and "id" and populate the datagridview ?

Comment: Thanks! Have you seen that I proposed test_nodelist instead of nodelist? That should return the same 3 items with your example and you should be able to loop at foreach(var entry in test_nodelist) and extract the entry.Descendants("Name") and entry.Descendants("id"), so you'll get then a .Value for each of those XElement. Of course I'll fix if there is something wrong, but it looked fine when I tried it, let me know...BTW I've seen they've fixed the parentheses, sorry for that.

Comment: If you're sure there is always a Name for each entry, then for example entry.Descendants("Name").First().Value and so on...

Comment: All good. "entry.Descendants("Name").First().Value" works fine but can't seem to use just "entry.Descendants("Name") .Value" as intellisense doesn't accept ".Value" in this statement

Comment: of course, you need First(), which is the problem? you need it since Descendants returns possible multiple nodes etc..

Comment: I Understand. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks to you, @BigVil ! bye :-)