# How to add xmlns to xml document?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to create a fairly simple XML document that looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employees xmlns="http://website.com/xsd/MQ">
    <employee>
        <id>00122731</id>
        <first-name>LUIS</first-name>
        <last-name>GARCIA</last-name>
        <subarea>4100</subarea>
        <cost-center>904</cost-center>
        <email-address>L.GARCIA@EMAIL.COM</email-address>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

I was able to get the basics by using this code but I need to add the xmlns attribute and I'm not figuring out how to do that.

```
var xmlDoc = new XElement("employees",
from e in listEmployees
select new XElement("employee",
    new XElement("id", e.EmployeeId),
    new XElement("first-name", e.FirstName),
    new XElement("last-name", e.LastName),
    new XElement("subarea", e.SubArea),
    new XElement("cost-center", e.CostCenter),
    new XElement("email-address", e.EmailAddress)));
```

This is my attempt to add it but I get an error that this would cause and invalid structure.

```
XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("employees",
        new XAttribute("xmlns", "http://website/xsd/MQ")),                        
        from e in listEmployees
        select new XElement("employee",
            new XElement("id", e.EmployeeId),
            new XElement("first-name", e.FirstName),
            new XElement("last-name", e.LastName),
            new XElement("subarea", e.SubArea),
            new XElement("cost-center", e.CostCenter),
            new XElement("email-address", e.EmailAddress))
);
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the link provided below this is what I came up with that worked.

```
XNamespace ns = "http://website/xsd/MQ";
var xmlDoc = new XElement(ns + "employees",
from e in listEmployees
select new XElement("employee",
    new XElement("id", e.EmployeeId),
    new XElement("first-name", e.FirstName),
    new XElement("last-name", e.LastName),
    new XElement("subarea", e.SubArea),
    new XElement("cost-center", e.CostCenter),
    new XElement("email-address", e.EmailAddress)));
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542073/xdocument-or-xmldocument/1542101#1542101 It has an example of using XNamespace to add the namespace.

Comment: Thanks...that link helped. I posted the updated code in my original post.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the namespace on all of your elements, not just the top one:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://website/xsd/MQ";
var xmlDoc = new XElement(ns + "employees",
    from e in listEmployees
    select new XElement(ns + "employee",
        new XElement(ns + "id", e.EmployeeId),
        new XElement(ns + "first-name", e.FirstName),
        new XElement(ns + "last-name", e.LastName),
        new XElement(ns + "subarea", e.SubArea),
        new XElement(ns + "cost-center", e.CostCenter),
        new XElement(ns + "email-address", e.EmailAddress)
    )
);
```

If that's too repetitive for you, you could make a convenience method:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://website/xsd/MQ";
private static XElement MQElement(string name, object contents)
{
    return new XElement(ns + name, contents);
}
```

then use it:

```
var xmlDoc = MQElement("employees",
    from e in listEmployees
    select MQElement("employee",
        MQElement("id", e.EmployeeId),
        MQElement("first-name", e.FirstName),
        MQElement("last-name", e.LastName),
        MQElement("subarea", e.SubArea),
        MQElement("cost-center", e.CostCenter),
        MQElement("email-address", e.EmailAddress)
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option to achieve same result is to construct `XElement` ignoring namespaces completely and then add them in separate code:

```
foreach (XElement e in xmlDoc.DescendantsAndSelf())
{
  if (e.Name.Namespace == "")
  {
    e.Name = ns + e.Name.LocalName;
  }
}
```