# C# xml file creation adding same attribute both of child and parent nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I am using c# to create a xml file, however I got some problem.
I would like to have both of parent and child nodes with a same attribute. But only one of those nodes has the attribute, even though I appended both of those.

**what I expected:**

```
<request>
    <transaction transactionId:"123">
        <transactionDetail transactionId:"123"></transactionDetail>
    </transaction>
</request>
```

**what I got:**

```
<request>
    <transaction>
        <transactionDetail transactionId:"123"></transactionDetail>
    </transaction>
</request>
```

or

```
<request>
    <transaction  transactionId:"123">
        <transactionDetail></transactionDetail>
    </transaction>
</request>
```

This is depends on the order that I write code (The node I append later has attribute). Could you please help me out to find what's causing this problem?

Also, I just wonder:

Does the order of appending (both of .AppendChild() & .Append() ) matter?

Can't I reuse attributes which are already appended in other nodes?

The following is the function to create xml file:

```
public ActionResult createXMLFile() {

            XmlDocument xmlFile = new XmlDocument();

            XmlNode request = xmlFile.CreateElement("request");
            XmlNode transaction= xmlFile.CreateElement("transaction");
            XmlNode transactionDetail= xmlFile.CreateElement("transactionDetail");


            XmlAttribute transactionId= xmlFile.CreateAttribute("transactionId");
            transactionId.Value = "123";

            transaction.Attributes.Append(transactionId);
            transactionDetail.Attributes.Append(transactionId);

            xmlFile.AppendChild(request);
            request.AppendChild(transaction);
            transaction.AppendChild(transactionDetail);

            string path ="somepath";

            xmlFile.Save(path);

    }
```

Thank you for reading my question. :)

Comment: You will need to clone the object. `XmlDocument` will have some odd behavior if you try reusing the same object on two different XML elements.

Comment: @user2896976 Ohh do I need to do so? That is sad when I have tens of elements to clone... But still, Thank you for letting me know and for your fast comment! :) If you put this as answer, I will accept it

Comment: @user2896976 is correct, you must use a separate `XmlAttribute` each time.  `XmlAttribute` has a [`ParentNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattribute.parentnode.aspx) property which is why the same instance cannot be used multiple times in the DOM hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted in the comments, you need to create two attributes, you can't reuse the same one:

```
var transactionId1 = xmlFile.CreateAttribute("transactionId");
transactionId1.Value = "123";
transaction.Attributes.Append(transactionId1);

var transactionId2 = xmlFile.CreateAttribute("transactionId");
transactionId2.Value = "123";
transactionDetail.Attributes.Append(transactionId2);
```

However, I'd suggest using LINQ to XML. You can create this XML far more declaratively:

```
var doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("request",
        new XElement("transaction", 
            new XAttribute("transactionId", "123"),
                new XElement("transactionDetail", new XAttribute("transactionId", "123"))
            )
        )
    );

doc.Save(path);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iLkjBj).

Comment: Hello, @CharlesMager. Thank you for the answer. However, since I am not familiar with the .net environment, could you please tell me what will be the biggest difference of using LINQ to XML? This structure seems way better than what I did, but I wonder what is happening in the computer... By putting `using System.Xml.Linq;` am I adding something like a library of java or source code in js??

Comment: It does require referencing a separate assembly, but it's part of the framework so it doesn't need including when you deploy. `XmlDocument` is part of the 'classic' DOM API that's been around since .NET was released whereas LINQ to XML is a newer API that was added with .NET 3.5 and is *far* nicer to use. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542073/xdocument-or-xmldocument) covers it better than I can in a comment.

Comment: Thank you for the reference! It is still confusing, but now I've got better understanding of it. I tried with the LINQ to XML and it is much faster to do code. Thanks again, and have a good day :)