# How to read XML document in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

First of all, sorry if this question is already answered, but i haven't found it.

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<data success="1" status="200">
    <id>SbBGk</id>
    <title/>
    <description/>
    <datetime>1341533193</datetime>
    <type>image/jpeg</type>
    <animated>false</animated>
    <width>2559</width>
    <height>1439</height>
    <size>521916</size>
    <views>1</views>
    <bandwidth>521916</bandwidth>
    <deletehash>eYZd3NNJHsbreD1</deletehash>
    <section/>
    <link>http://i.imgur.com/SbBGk.jpg</link>
</data>
```

I want to get the `id` as a string. Any ideas?

Note: The XML file is a web response, that i retrieve using:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
byte[] response = w.UploadValues("https://api.imgur.com/3/upload.xml", values);
string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
doc.LoadXml(xml);
```

Comment: Look into Xpath see : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx(v=vs.110).aspx & https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ditch `XmlDocument`. It's old and has been superseded by `XDocument`. Once you've got a valid `XDocument`, `var id=(string)doc.Root.Element("id");` will do you.

Comment: Consider using [`XDocument.Load()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838321(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Changed to `XDocument` and `var id=(string)doc.Root.Element("id");` worked! Thanks

Comment: Nice explanation XDocument over XMLDocument https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542073/xdocument-or-xmldocument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using XMLDocument, use XDocument.

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
doc.Load(xml);
string id = doc.Root.Element("id").Value;
```