# XML response processing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting raw XML response from eBay API call. Now I have to grab values from XML and add those values to ViewModel object then return data to my View. I have already tried few things bellow but I am unable to grab XML response items and assign to ViewModel. Please check each part of code below and let me know if you have any solution. I don't need working code coz i know you cant test it since its uncompleted. Just simple hints would enough, however, i am new with c#. Thanks a lot in advance

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Search(string OperationName, string calltype, string page, string keywords, string type, string location, string condition, string min, string max, string negative, string minFeedback, string maxFeedback, string drange, string categoryId)
        {
            string AppId = "KavinHim-BestProd-PRD-785446bf1-666"; //api configs
            string BaseUrl = "http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME="; //base url api end point

            if (calltype == "categoryClick")
            {
                string Url = BaseUrl + OperationName + "&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=" + AppId + "&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&categoryId=" + categoryId + "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=2&paginationInput.pageNumber=" + page + "";
                var client = new RestClient(Url);
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
                request.Method = Method.GET;
                request.Parameters.Clear();
                var xmlResponse = client.Execute(request).Content;

                XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                xdoc.LoadXml(new WebClient().DownloadString(xmlResponse));


                var items = new List<EbayDataViewModel>();

                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                   //add items from xml data to EbayDataViewModel object

                }

            }
            return View();
        }
```

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using WebApplication2.Models;

namespace WebApplication2.ViewModels
{
    public class EbayDataViewModel
    {
        public string EbayImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string EbayTitle { get; set; }
        public string NumberOfSales { get; set; }
        public string NumberOfWatch { get; set; }
    }


}
```

XML Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<findItemsByCategoryResponse xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">

<ack>Success</ack>

<version>1.13.0</version>

<timestamp>2017-10-14T08:27:04.876Z</timestamp>


-<searchResult count="2">


-<item>

<itemId>332390426668</itemId>

<title>حجاب روحاني يتحرك,حجاب الغزال أوالظبي ,أقوى حجاب للمحبة والزواج ,حرز حي يتفاعل </title>

<globalId>EBAY-US</globalId>


-<primaryCategory>

<categoryId>162918</categoryId>

<categoryName>Islamic</categoryName>

</primaryCategory>

<galleryURL>http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/m/mf7QDRtgSn83eQF23aLFD_Q/140.jpg</galleryURL>

<viewItemURL>http://www.ebay.com/itm/-/332390426668</viewItemURL>

<paymentMethod>PayPal</paymentMethod>

<autoPay>true</autoPay>

<postalCode>04468</postalCode>

<location>Old Town,ME,USA</location>

<country>US</country>


-<shippingInfo>

<shippingServiceCost currencyId="USD">0.0</shippingServiceCost>

<shippingType>FlatDomesticCalculatedInternational</shippingType>

<shipToLocations>Worldwide</shipToLocations>

<expeditedShipping>false</expeditedShipping>

<oneDayShippingAvailable>false</oneDayShippingAvailable>

<handlingTime>1</handlingTime>

</shippingInfo>


-<sellingStatus>

<currentPrice currencyId="USD">350.0</currentPrice>

<convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="USD">350.0</convertedCurrentPrice>

<sellingState>Active</sellingState>

<timeLeft>P10DT14H19M17S</timeLeft>

</sellingStatus>


-<listingInfo>

<bestOfferEnabled>true</bestOfferEnabled>

<buyItNowAvailable>false</buyItNowAvailable>

<startTime>2017-09-24T22:46:21.000Z</startTime>

<endTime>2017-10-24T22:46:21.000Z</endTime>

<listingType>StoreInventory</listingType>

<gift>false</gift>

<watchCount>6</watchCount>

</listingInfo>

<returnsAccepted>true</returnsAccepted>

<galleryPlusPictureURL>http://galleryplus.ebayimg.com/ws/web/332390426668_1_1_1.jpg</galleryPlusPictureURL>

<isMultiVariationListing>false</isMultiVariationListing>

<topRatedListing>false</topRatedListing>

</item>


-<item>

<itemId>382249935959</itemId>

<title>Circa 900 AD Authentic Viking Bronze Snake Bracelet Found In Latvia Excavation</title>

<globalId>EBAY-US</globalId>


-<primaryCategory>

<categoryId>162920</categoryId>

<categoryName>Viking</categoryName>

</primaryCategory>

<galleryURL>http://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/m/mf73oCtiHN2GGSZlIY0VP7Q/140.jpg</galleryURL>

<viewItemURL>http://www.ebay.com/itm/Circa-900-AD-Authentic-Viking-Bronze-Snake-Bracelet-Found-Latvia-Excavation-/382249935959</viewItemURL>

<paymentMethod>PayPal</paymentMethod>

<autoPay>true</autoPay>

<postalCode>80932</postalCode>

<location>Colorado Springs,CO,USA</location>

<country>US</country>


-<shippingInfo>

<shippingServiceCost currencyId="USD">0.0</shippingServiceCost>

<shippingType>Free</shippingType>

<shipToLocations>Worldwide</shipToLocations>

<expeditedShipping>false</expeditedShipping>

<oneDayShippingAvailable>false</oneDayShippingAvailable>

<handlingTime>1</handlingTime>

</shippingInfo>


-<sellingStatus>

<currentPrice currencyId="USD">52.0</currentPrice>

<convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="USD">52.0</convertedCurrentPrice>

<sellingState>Active</sellingState>

<timeLeft>P28DT14H3M39S</timeLeft>

</sellingStatus>


-<listingInfo>

<bestOfferEnabled>false</bestOfferEnabled>

<buyItNowAvailable>false</buyItNowAvailable>

<startTime>2017-10-12T22:30:43.000Z</startTime>

<endTime>2017-11-11T22:30:43.000Z</endTime>

<listingType>FixedPrice</listingType>

<gift>false</gift>

<watchCount>1</watchCount>

</listingInfo>

<returnsAccepted>true</returnsAccepted>

<isMultiVariationListing>false</isMultiVariationListing>

<topRatedListing>true</topRatedListing>

</item>

</searchResult>


-<paginationOutput>

<pageNumber>1</pageNumber>

<entriesPerPage>2</entriesPerPage>

<totalPages>27113</totalPages>

<totalEntries>54226</totalEntries>

</paginationOutput>

<itemSearchURL>http://www.ebay.com/sch/37903/i.html?_ddo=1&_ipg=2&_pgn=1</itemSearchURL>

</findItemsByCategoryResponse>
```

Comment: You can access values from you `XmlDocument` to populate your model using [XmlDocument.SelectNodes Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectnodes(v=vs.110).aspx). You shouldn't have to specify very complex xpath - see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_examples.asp) for some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using .NET Version 3.0 or lower, It's highly recommend to use `XDocument` over `XmlDocument`: [reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542073/xdocument-or-xmldocument)

Anyway, you can use `.Descendants()` to get all descendants, and then compare the local name of all its elements to see if there is an element whose local name matches the name of **item**.

**(Tested)**

```
var items = new List<EbayDataViewModel>();

// You can directly plug the url in with .Load() method.
// No need to create HttpClient to download the response as string and then
// parse.
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(url);

// Since you're only interested in <item> collections within <searchResult>
var searchResultItems = xdoc.Descendants()
    .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "item");

foreach (var sri in searchResultItems)
{
   // Get all child xml elements
   var childElements = sri.Elements();

   var itemId = childElements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "itemId");
   var title = childElements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "title");

   //add items from xml data to EbayDataViewModel object
    items.Add(new EbayDataViewModel {
        EbayTitle = title == null? Stirng.Empty : title.Value,
        ...
    });
}

return items;
```

**Since there are lots of checking and comparison, writing extention methods for those would be useful.**

```
public static class XElementExtensions
{
    public static XElement LocalNameElement(this XElement parent, string localName)
    {
        return parent.Elements().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == localName);

    public static IEnumerable<XElement> LocalNameElements(this XElement parent, string localName)
    {
        return parent.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == localName);
    }

    public static string LocalNameElementValue(this XElement parent, string localName)
    {
        var element = parent.LocalNameElement(localName);
        return element == null? String.Empty : element.Value;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/hpDPiw check this screen shot. i am getting error : 'Illegal characters in path.'

Comment: Can you give me the url so that I can plug it to my Rest client?

Comment: // working url: http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByCategory&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=KavinHim-BestProd-PRD-78e3e6bf1-97d9ef25&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&categoryId=37903&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=100&paginationInput.pageNumber=4

Comment: any solution? @David Liang

Comment: No, you just need to plug your url directly to `XDocument.Load()`. You don't need to create a client and download the response as string. @JohnLk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156723/discussion-between-david-liang-and-john-lk).

Comment: Thanks @David Liang

Answer (score 0):

One way would be accessing the *item* node values from your `XmlDocument` using XPath query strings. You'll probably want to loop over the response items and create new ViewModel objects to populate your list of ViewModels:

```
var items = new List<EbayDataViewModel>();
var responseItems = xdoc.SelectNodes("item");
foreach (responseItem in responseItems)
{
    items.Add(new EbayDataViewModel() 
        { EbayImageUrl = responseItem.SelectSingleNode("galleryURL").InnerText,
          EbayTitle = responseItem.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText,
          NumberOfSales = responseItem.SelectSingleNode("").InnerText,
          NumberOfWatch = responseItem.SelectSingleNode("").InnerText
        });
}
```

Note: I couldn't find anything that looked like "NumberOfSales or NumberOfWatch" in the XML Response, so those XPaths will need to be filled in.

See [XmlDocument.SelectNodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectnodes(v=vs.110).aspx) for documentation on this method.