# Grabbing a headers attribute variable from XML

Tags: c#, xml, nodes

I am making an API call to a service, and receiving an big XML back. I am looking to grab the unique info that is attached to a header, but cannot find out how to do it.

XML call -

```
<InvDetailRequest>
    <InvDetailRequestHeader invDate="2023-06-14T18:51:50-04:00" invID="IN305">
```

I want to grab the InvDate, and the InvID, but do not know how.

In another part of my code, I am using this loop to grab all the ID's attached. But grabbing the singleNode inner text does not work.

```
XmlDocument doc = context.Data.ToXmlDocument();

XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/DataRequest/Source/AttachmentInfo/Attachment");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)  
{
    //Grab single node here - node.SelectSingleNode("ID").InnerText
}
```

I was able to get some ouput with

```
doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//InvDetailRequest").InnerXml)
```

But I do not know how to single down the specific InvID variable to assign elsewhere.

Comment: You have to post the real XML , not just one line and post the whole code you have tried already and what is the problem and  with line of code.

Comment: `invDate` and `invID` arn't nodes they are attributes of a node, so when you have the node call `node.Attributes["invDate"]` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.attributes?view=net-7.0 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlattributecollection.itemof?view=net-7.0#system-xml-xmlattributecollection-itemof(system-string)

Comment: isn't it rather obvious, why your first code sample fails? this `"/DataRequest/Source/AttachmentInfo/Attachment"` seems to have nothing to do with the xml structure you have provided `InvDetailRequest/InvDetailRequestHeader` ?!?

Comment: @Serge the whole xml is about 800 lines long, Ill edit it to increase what I show by a bit. I just didnt wanna info overload

Comment: @RandRandom sorry for the confusion, that /datarequest example is from another part of the code. 

The solution to my problem was the node.Attributes["Variable"]. I did not know that was considered an attribute, and not a node. thank you!

Comment: @Phantom But at least you have to post a valid version

Answer (score 0):

if you are able to fix your xml, you can use this code

```
var result = XDocument.Parse(xml).Root
      .Descendants()   // or .Descendants("InvDetailRequestHeader")
      .Select(e => new { invDate = e.Attribute("invDate").Value, 
                         invID = e.Attribute("invID").Value })
      .FirstOrDefault();   // or ToList()
```

Comment: Just want to point out this is using `System.Xml.Linq` while OP is using `System.Xml` which has different syntax/classes. here you may find the difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542073

Comment: @RandRandom What OP is using doesn't work

Comment: OP is just bad at copy and pasting :)